# Install Ubuntu Mate on Raid 1

Tags: boot, system-installation, raid, mate

I wanna install ubuntu mate desktop 14.04 LTS on Raid 1 - preferably with LVM and Encryption.

tha farthest i got so far is. booting live system installing mdadm, creating a raid starting installation. (then i wanted to use brtfs instrat of ext - and i screwed everything up so that i couldnt start the installation) at the second try with just leaving the defaults it worked it just could not install grub - i told to try it again and it seemed to work (there was no error message) but it did not boot. - the thing is (i think) how will the freshly installed system know that it is a raid - because if i goo to boot option in bios i of course still see both disks seperately and no raid - where should it try to boot from. (it didnt worked either way)

other question i have is if i need for the raid to be synced to start the installation.

i've read the thing with alternate isntallation but this is not available anymore - and i want to avoid installing server - but i think this is the next thing im goint to try.

i just tried to install ubuntu on one disk (suceed ^^) and now add the seccond - but with the normal commands to create a new raid at least the first disk (od course) is busy and im afraid the system will freeze if i deactivate it ^^

ok therefore i will just tr this now https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-software-raid1-on-a-running-system-incl-grub2-configuration-ubuntu-10.04

if anything has already experience with what im tryin to do. - please help me :D

Comment: aand i miserably failed - booting now completely broken yey ^^ - i thinkg im gonna eighter try it with ubuntu server anyway or just not make use of a raid..

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar, but without LVM and encryption. You may perhaps still find something from the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/660023/how-to-install-ubuntu-14-04-64-bit-with-a-dual-boot-raid-1-partition-on-an-uefi), especially if your system boots via EFI.

Comment: thank you very much, i did had a brief loock at it and would have helped me quiete well i think, but the encryption would have set some extra challenges i'm sure..
anyway i did it already the following way:

- installed the current server versions on raid 1 ( because you can there)
- installed desktop (3 hours) ^^
- and as for encryption i just took the option fore encrypt home folder. - because it was still to hard for me.

then i did proper encyption for the data drives as well as brtfs and snaphots and lvm - i learned a lot and i took me days again.
but i will have a look if i start over.